# Mobius Transformation 2 conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

I just a wonder if there exist a Mobius Transformation where f(0)=1 and f(z)=0=f(-z) for some z?

Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $z = \infty$, sure. For $z = 0$, no, because mobius transformations are functions, and $f(0)$ can't be both $0$ and $1$ at the same time. For other $z\neq 0$, no, because Mobius transformations are bijective on the Riemann sphere, and specifically injective.